# When I train a VGG with tensorflow 2.0, why my accuracy do not increase and only stay about 25%

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, vgg-net

```
def get_model():
    gmodel=Sequential([

        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)),
        Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D((1,1),strides=2,padding='same'),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D((1,1), strides=2, padding='same'),
        Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D((1,1), strides=2, padding='same'),
        Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D((1,1), strides=2, padding='same'),
        Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D((1,1), strides=2, padding='same'),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(4, activation='softmax')

])


    return gmodel
model=get_model()
model.compile(
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),
loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
metrics=['accuracy']
)
history=model.fit(train,epochs=5)
```

I want to use VGG model to classify picture to 4 categories, but the accuracy is always about 25%. I have check the picture and labels, both of them are correct and I also try some other model and optimizer, but the accuracy do not have huge improve as well. What should I do. My GPU is 2070 ,tensorflow is 2.0 and python is 3.6

Answer (score 2):

The pooling layers

```
MaxPooling2D((1,1),strides=2,padding='same')
```

is causing information-loss. The pooling window is lesser than stride. This is working essentially by throwing away the information on every alternate pixel. So, that could be a reason why the model isn't learning.
Just changing the pooling layer to:

```
MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding='SAME')
```

could resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for not getting a good accuracy in image classification problem is less amount of data. So, you have to use pre-trained VGG-16 model for getting good accuracy. Like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras import layers

vgg = VGG16(input_shape = (256, 256, 3), include_top = False, weights = "imagenet")

for layer in vgg.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

x = layers.Flatten()(vgg.output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(4, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(vgg.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train, epochs = 10, verbose=1)
```

Please change the hyper-parameters of above code according to your need, especially input shape. Also note that, these pre-trained model required internet connection to download weights.

Comment: When I train this model, the accuracy is decreasing. I think may be some part of my code have some mistake but I am not sure

Comment: What images are you classifying ? Please show me the full code.

Comment: How to give you code and images. Sorry I am a rooky

Comment: How to give you dataset and full code in stackoverflow. Sorry I am a rookie user

Answer (score 0):

One way to better diagnose your problem is to try and understand not only the top choice that your model is picking, but also the second, third and fourth choices, and the probabilities associated with each. To do this, I would recommend adding an additional loss function that tells you how frequently the second choice is correct. This might also give you more information about whether or not something is going wrong.

Here is some code that I've used:

```
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    metric_top_sparse = tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=1, name="sparse_top_1_acc", dtype=None)
    metric_top2_sparse = tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=2, name="sparse_top_2_acc", dtype=None)
```

Comment: When I use second and third loss, it show that TypeError: call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: You can put them in the metrics function instead of in the loss function and look at them. See as follows: 
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=loss,
                           metrics=[metric_top_sparse,
                                    metric_top2_sparse])